# setting up a gcloud appspot domain - Getting URL not found error

Tags: html, google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I am currently trying to setup a gcloud appspot domain. I am consistently getting this error when I attempt to open up my appspot project on the browser:

Error: Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Here is my code. How can I fix this?

app.yaml -

```
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

---

main.go -

```
package app

func main() {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the HTTP 404 error is that the files your handlers are looking for are not there, or are not in the correct directory. Meaning there has to be an index.html in the directory 'www', which must be located in the root directory of your app.yaml deployment.

For example if your [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref) and main.go files are in the directory /myapp, the full path of the file index.html has to be /myapp/www/index.html.

Answer (score 0):

just to add...

I was running the [Google Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website) and missed the file structure requirement. My index.html file was not in the www directory.  Once I created the www directory and moved the index.html file there the tutorial executed correctly.

The final structure was:

- app.yaml
- www

  - index.html

As was pointed out in the above answer, its likely your directory/file structure may be the issue.